# Can't get influx query to populate Grafana table correctly

Tags: grafana, influxdb

When performing the following query via SSH session directly on the influx database I get the following data

Query

```
SELECT TOP("count","src_ip",10) FROM (SELECT count("action") FROM "autogen"."tail_ip_block_log" WHERE ("action" = 'block' AND "direction" = 'in') GROUP BY "src_ip")
```

Output

```
name: tail_ip_block_log
time top  src_ip
---- ---  ------
0    1461 46.17.102.30
0    1460 91.210.107.28
0    1451 91.240.118.225
0    1174 209.141.43.233
0    952  79.124.58.22
0    882  79.124.62.78
0    835  79.124.62.82
0    833  79.124.62.86
0    815  79.124.62.130
0    521  78.128.114.78
```

However when I try this same query on a Grafana table (new table not the old one)

Query

```
SELECT TOP("count","src_ip",10) FROM (SELECT count("action") FROM "autogen"."tail_ip_block_log" WHERE ("action" = 'block' AND "direction" = 'in') GROUP BY "src_ip")
```

Output
[Table screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skhtP.png)

I only get the following columns available.
"time" and "count" (see pic)

If I choose to format as a time series then I am about to almost get the information I need by using joins but then it takes away the top 10 entries and only shows me one.

Plus I feel like it should be showing me the count and src_ip and then I could just transform the time column to hide it.

Please help.

I have tried everything to get this to work in the new table panel in grafana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed this was working again this morning, grafana version is now 9.4.7 so I am guessing this was a bug.